# Explanation for staircase in training of a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have tried to create a Keras model with my own data. After about a few epochs something strange happened (like a staircase) that I can't explain to myself.

[Result of the training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdklU.png)

Do you know by chance what the event after about 270 epochs means?

Comment: would you please add some code, at least the parts of your optimizer, where the scheduler comes into play? So other here can profit from your complete question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer your question without seeing the code

To my eyes this looks like you might have a **learning rate scheduler** or something else that adjusts your learning rate (see keras documentation [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/#learningratescheduler)).

```
keras.callbacks.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(schedule, verbose=0)
```

And in case you re lost with what a scheduler is to begin with (see
 this [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-rate-schedules-and-adaptive-learning-rate-methods-for-deep-learning-2c8f433990d1)):

> Learning rate schedules seek to adjust the learning rate during training by reducing the learning rate according to a pre-defined
>   schedule. Common learning rate schedules include time-based decay,
>   step decay and exponential decay.